# parameter in SCD module - historical type

Tags: t-sql, ssis

When new record is added in SCD component type historical, OLE DB Command execute the query:

```
UPDATE [table] SET [ExpirationDate] = ? WHERE [ID] = ? AND [ExpirationDate] = '9999-12-31'
```

How to fix that query in order to SET [ExpirationDate] = [ImportDate] when change occure.
Query:

```
UPDATE [table] SET [ExpirationDate] = [ImportDate] WHERE [ID] = ? AND [ExpirationDate] = '9999-12-31'
```

generates error:

```
OLE DB provider used by the OLE DB adapter cannot convert between 
types DT_DBTIMESTAMP2 and DT_NUMERIC for Param_0
```

I don't understand it because both [ExpirationDate] and [ImportDate] have the same type (datetime2). How to achieve this update when historical change occures?

Comment: What is [ImportDate]? Is it another column in your table?

Comment: IMHO, ditch the SCD component - it's slow, inflexible and only covers about 80% of requirements. I always use staging tables and SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

The error message in the OLEDB cmd is referring to how the "?" is mapped.  Is ID numeric and is param_0 on the next tab mapped to a date field?

The way that you should set up this command would be like this:

```
UPDATE [table] SET [ExpirationDate] = ? WHERE [ID] = ? AND [ExpirationDate] = '9999-12-31'
```

On the following tab, you will have two parameters, map the first to [ImportDate] and the second to the ID field.  Parameters are mapped in ordinal order.

Comment: I've change the mappings (switched ExpirationDate to ImportDate) But nothing happens. SCD doesn;t work propoerly (doesn't detect changes). The only case it works is when ExpirationDate is null by default. I've made dump shortcut: before and after SCD gave sql task component. First changes 9999-12-31 to nulls and second changes nulls to 9999-12-31

Comment: You need to also change the command text to what I posted. There should be two parameters, otherwise you are merely updating one column with another from the same row.

Comment: the command was the same UPDATE [table] SET [ExpirationDate] = ? WHERE [ID] = ? ...

Comment: Could you show an image of how the column mappings tab is configured?

Comment: I have figured out what's happend. Previousely I didn't make changes in main SCD component which point at the current row ( [ExpirationDate] = '9999...) . Now it's ok.